# How to replace new line with %0D%0A with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript code that can replace new lines with %0D%0A

I need the same code in PHP.

This is how my JavaScript code looks like:

```
text = text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '%0D%0A');
```

I tried with PHP but I am getting only one line without newlines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need *regular expressions* for that. Simple string replacement will be enough.
Use **[str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace)** function:

```
$test = 'Some very long text with multiple lines...';
$newText = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '%0D%0A', $text);
```

New line character differs in various systems. It's not a good idea to hard-code `\n\r`. Better solution is to use `PHP_EOL` constant.

Comment: PHP_EOL is not always a good solution. It takes actual PHP environment  related value. So if PHP runs under Windows it will be `\r\n` value. What if I got string which contains only `\n` as a new-line character?

Comment: @barell you're right but I assumed that the OP expects the environment related value.

Comment: @user1477332 It only depends on what you already need. You asked about: how to replace `\n\r` with `%0D%0A` in PHP so the answer is `str_replace('\n\r', '%0D%0A', $text)`. You can use PHP_EOL constant of course but you need to remember it's value depends on operating system the PHP is running on. So this value may vary.

Answer (score 0):

a literal translation of your java code into php could use  preg_replace 
http://www.php.net/preg_replace

```
<?php
$text = "some text";
$text = preg_replace("\r\n","%0D%0A",$text);
?>
```

Comment: There is no need to use `preg_replace` to do simple string replacements. Use `str_replace` instead - it is much faster.

Comment: Last dollar sign is missing.